# How can I solve a Xamarin IOS Error MT5212 (Native linking failed, duplicate symbol) caused by third party nugets?

Tags: ios, xamarin, emgucv, onnx

I'm working on a project that uses both OpenCV and ONNX for some specialized text recognition purposes.
We are developing the mobile application on Xamarin with targets for both Android and IOS.
For the OpenCV part we are using the EmguCV library (version 4.5.5.4823) and for ONNX we are using ONNXRuntime from the nuget repository, Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime (version 1.14.0).
The issue I am experiencing is that on iOS the build process stops at the linking phase of the main application with this kind of errors:

/MTOUCH: Error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: ''google::protobuf::internal::EpsCopyInputStream::ReadArenaString(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr*, google::protobuf::Arena*)''. (MT5212)

I've tried to change the MTOUCH --registrar setting to static (as some sources suggest) but the error is there with static set.
While if I don't set it to static I have a similar but different error:

/MTOUCH: Error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: ''_VP8DecompressAlphaRows''. (MT5212)
/MTOUCH: Error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/WebP.a(libwebpdecode_la-alpha_dec.o) (Location related to previous error) (MT5213)
They are essentialy the same kind of error, but on different library depending on how i set the behavior of the linker (or if I build for a simulator vs actual device, which actually changes the default for the same setting).

So the effect is that when i compile with the dyncamic registrar protobuf has duplicate symbols (looking at the source, the two libraries use protobuf and they use different versions of it)
if I switch to static the issue is with the libwebpdecode library that is probably in conflict with something used by xamarin itself

Do you have any suggestion on what I might try to do?

I've tried to change the MTOUCH --registrar setting to static (as stated above) but it did not solve the issue.
I've also tried to add a -gcc_flags -dead_strip option to the linker, and while this actually allowed the linking to work caused the application to be unusable (crashes at start).